# Adjusting for confounding with a negative control outcome

Tags: regression, causality, confounding

When studying the effect of an exposure $T$ on an outcome $Y$, we can control for measured confounders $X$, but the treatment effect can still be biased by residual confounding due to unmeasured confounders $U$. One approach for detecting this kind of bias is to use a negative control outcome $N$ (e.g. [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8118596/)), which is not caused by $T$ but shares the same confounder $U$. If, after adjusting for confounders $X$ using a regression model (for example), there a non-zero effect of $T$ on $N$, then we know there is residual confounding.

This approach can detect confounding, but not necessarily estimate the magnitude of confounding bias, as explained in eAppendix 3 of [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3053408/) paper. The issue is that the effect of $U$ on $N$ is not necessarily equal to the effect of $U$ on $Y$.

However, if one views $N$ as a surrogate for unmeasured confounding, then why can we not simply add it as a covariate in our original regression model? That is, why can we not adjust our estimates of the effect of $T$ on $Y$ by adding $N$ to our measured confounders $X$?

I usually avoid adjusting for any post-treatment variable as it could lead to collider bias, but by assumption, $Y$ is not associated with $N$, so this is not an issue. That said, there could be M-bias. Is that the reason why this should be avoided?

Comment: Off-hand, I'd say that as $N$ isn't related to $T,$ it shouldn't (theoretically) change your regression coefficients much, if at all.

Comment: @AdrianKeister $N$ shares a common cause ($U$) with $T$, so even though it is not causally related, it can be strongly correlated because of the strength of the unmeasured confounder.

Comment: But it won't shut off the backdoor path; you can always try simulating this experience with some known example.

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting thought, but naively, conditioning on $N$ doesn't closes the backdoor path $T \leftarrow U \rightarrow Y$.
See the orange path in this DAG:
[image]

It can be shown using a fairly simple simulation based on this DAG:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

def generate_data(seed, M=10000):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)

    x = rng.normal(size=M)
    u = rng.normal(size=M)

    t_logit = 1 + 0.5*x + 1*u + rng.normal(size=M)
    t_propensity = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-t_logit))
    t = rng.binomial(1, t_propensity)

    y = 1 + 2*t + 0.5*x + 1*u + rng.normal(size=M)

    n = 1 + 0.5*x + 1*u + rng.normal(size=M) # not affected by t

    data = pd.DataFrame({
        "x": x, "u": u, "t": t,
        "y": y, "n": n,
    })
    # data.head()
    return data
```

Which running a 100 times:

```py
res = []
for i in range(100):
    data = generate_data(i)
    
    correct = smf.ols("y ~ 1 + t + x + u", data=data).fit().params['t']
    misspecified = smf.ols("y ~ 1 + t + x", data=data).fit().params['t']
    nc_adjusted = smf.ols("y ~ 1 + t + x + n", data=data).fit().params['t']
    
    res.append((correct, misspecified, nc_adjusted))

res = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["correct", "misspecified", "neg_control_adjusted"])
res.head()
```

Shows the estimates adjusting for negative controls is still biased:
[image]

However, if you play around with the correlation between $U$ and $N$ you are correct to assume that the stronger the correlation is the smaller the bias is (even bounded by the model with $U$ to the model without $U$) because $N$ becomes $U$ from information perspective:
[image]

Which is in line with the line of work exploring the [adjustment for proxies of confounders](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7746017/) (which I recommend).

Comment: This is very helpful, @ehudk. Can you think of the potential risks of this approach? Adjusting for $U$ cannot lead to collider bias, because it is not downstream from $T$, but is there some other type of bias I would risk introducing by adjusting for $N$?

Comment: You have to be very certain $N$ is not affected by $T$ because otherwise you might introduce post-treatment adjustment bias. However, my main concern with this approach (personally) is temporality issues. (Negative) outcomes occur during follow-up and are not available during baseline. This may hinder generalizability or usability of conclusions (think of a physician needing to enter patient's details into some risk calculator during meeting, they won't have access to future events [outcomes])